# c# Make instance of another class

Tags: c#

I got 2 classes:

```
class Persoon {

    List<Rekening> rekeningen = new List<Rekening>();

    public String Naam { get; set; }

    public void MaakNieuweRekening { 


    }

    public Persoon(string naam) 
    {
        Naam = naam;

    }
}

class Rekening {

    public Rekening(int rekeningsnummer, int saldo)
    {
        RekeningsNummer = rekeningsnummer;
        Saldo = saldo;
    }
```

But I can't figure out why I can't do this in the "Persoon" class:
rekeningen.add(new Rekening(500,500));

I just want to hold for each Persoon a list of all his bank accounts that he can make.

Comment: You have a typo `public void MaakNieuweRekening` <- here.

Comment: Wow stupid mistake -.- MaakNieuweRekening() fixed it. Ty!

Answer (score 3):

in your Rekening class you need to decalre variable for RekeningsNummer  and Saldo

like this :

```
int RekeningsNummer  = 0;
int Saldo = 0;
```